# Counting matrices formed from 180 exactly elements

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics

> Let $A$ be a set of 180 elements. How many matrices of arbitrary dimension can be formed by using each element of set $A$ exactly once?

My approach was: (taking elements one at a time (180 elements, 18 ways in which they can be represented as a product of two; taking two at a time , (90 elements, 12 ways ) ...and so on,why i couldn't get it by this process? Is there any shorter approach?

Comment: Note: I edited the question statement for English clarity, but if I haven't preserved the meaning then please roll back the edit.

Comment: 198 seems kind of too small? Seeing how there are 180! many $1\times 180$ matrices?

Comment: @bonsoon do you have a  solution?

Comment: (i) How many ways can you write $180=m\times n$? (ii) Given a matrix with $180$ places, in how many ways can you assign the elements of $A$ to the places?